# Review count in the status bar showing review items when there are none

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

As the picture illustrates the review count in the status bar showing review items when there are none.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we rolled out the "pending reviews" indicator, we had to make an unfortunate concession to the fact that personalizing it for each user is too computationally expensive. The end result is that the number of pending reviews in the top bar is the *total* count of still active reviews in the system, including ones that are no longer available to you. (Plus some caching may be at play.)

We'd been thinking about ways to make this experience better, but I'm not sure what the status of that is right now.

Comment: Please fix it. Its driving me insane. I will even write the entire messaging system myself if needed. :)

Comment: @racefever Why driving you insane? It's a great way to know if the site is behind on its review tasks.

Comment: @JoErNanO I don't like to see the badge with a random number for which I have no control. I just blocked it with a browser plug-in. BTW, I don't know much of the SE architecture, but is it too far out to use something like websockets for such a feature?

Answer (score 2):

If you have uBlock origin installed on your browser you can block the badge from appearing. I did that to ease the pain and suffering.